# Angular 9: ANSI encoded text file shows � for ” (curly quotes) when reading .txt from url using http.get

Tags: angular, utf-8, angular9, http-get, non-unicode

I am trying to read/get data from URL of text file as below. It gives proper data when txt file encoding is UTF-8 but when encoding type is ANSI, it is showing �  for ” curly quotes.

```
    let url='www.test.com/test.txt';
    return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'text' });
```

Can anyone please let me know how I can get data from URL of text file with encoding type ANSI?

Comment: Is your webserver *serving* the file with the correct Content-Type header…?! If it's served as UTF-8 but actually contains ANSI, well, yes, you'll get encoding problems.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for the quick reply. Yes there are files with encoding type ANSI and UTF-8 both. So I need to handle in angular to read it's content. Can you suggest any plugin or any other workaround for this case?

Comment: @Darshana: your **server** needs to provide the correct content-type header *with* the precise encoding to use to read the file or Angular won't be able to get it right. If your server doesn't **know** the correct encoding for each file, then that's your problem: fix this. Ideally by converting [everything to UTF-8](https://utf8everywhere.org/).